# Handle Multiple Mysql Database connection Failure

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I'm Stuck at the situation where more than 1 Database connection needs to be handle. For example :

```
function update_user()
{
 #Establish connection with DB1
 #Update the user

 # Close connection with DB1
 #Establish connection with DB2
 #Update the user

 # Close connection with DB2
 #Establish connection with DB3
 #Update the user

}
```

> In the above Algorithm I have to establish connection one by one and
>   update the user from the corresponding tables.
>
> **My Question is** : **What happened when any of the DB connection failed and how can i roll back for the above executions ?**
>   For Example if DB1 Connection executes successfully and DB2 connection failed than what is the best way to roll back the execution of DB1.
>
> **My Proposed Solution** : I think i can use the PHP to handle this, i
>   just need to maintain the Array with updated records and ids. and
>   Execute the Update query again for DB1 connection. But this case also
>   fails when that time the DB1 Connection also got failed. So i can't
>   handle it with PHP. what could be the solution ?

Comment: why dont you go for php error handling like `try catch`.. and take a `$flag=0` on the top of your php code,, and if any exception is there `increament the flag` so if at the end of the code the flag is not zero than you can `rollback` both the databases

Comment: but this solution could be failed when i rollback with DB1 and it also got failed. actually my all databases on same server and if any 1 is failed than all databases are goes down.

Comment: ,, dont rollback na.. if your `$flag=0` at the end of the file than dont do anything.. otherwise `rollback both the dbs`...

Comment: for `rollback  both the dbs` i have to establish connection with DB1 and at the time of establishing the connection if Connection is got failed with DB1 than it is not possible to rollback the execution done with DB1.

Comment: you are not trying to understand.. if you havent established the connection the db1 than you can only rollback db2... and if you havent established conn with db2 than rollback db1 and if not connected to any of the db than you dont need to do any rollback, and if you got error after connecting to both the dbs than rollback both... got it? just use number of flags to manage this...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using transactions within MySQL.

I would suggest starting a transaction after opening each connection (for each connection) and committing them when all the updates have succeeded or rolling them all back when they fail. This will ensure no rows are updated unless all of the updates succeed.

For more information on transactions, see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Pseudo Code:

```
# Try
    # Establish connection with DB1
    # Create a transaction for DB1 connection 
    # Update the user

    # Establish connection with DB2
    # Create a transaction for DB2 connection
    # Update the user

    # Establish connection with DB3
    # Create a transaction for DB3 connection
    # Update the user

    # Commit all transactions
# Catch
    # Rollback all transactions, rethrow exception
# Finally
    # Close all connections
```

Comment: transaction will work for a single db only.. here OP is asking for multiple DBs...

Comment: I have multiple DBs and Transactions is possible only for single DB.

Comment: My suggestion is creating a transaction for each connection, then handling them all on error/success.

Comment: @LiamSymonds could you please explain in brief.

Comment: @LiamSymonds i can't perform roll back as my all databases on same server and if any 1 of them got failed that means all are down.

Comment: By using a transaction this means no data would have touched the table and nothing will need to rollback. When your server comes back up, the user will not have been updated. I believe this is what you are asking for.